# Merge two wordpress databases that have the same structure but one has newer data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have seen that this may be similar to other posts on here but none of them managed to answer my issue.

I have two wordpress sites (staging and live) and I have been doing some work on the staging however the live site is still active and has had posts / comments etc... being added while I made the staging changes.

Now I need to combine the two databases via phpmyadmin so it has the changes made on staging but also all of the new content from live, reading on other posts I have seen the following suggested and have done it for every table in the database but it doesn't seem to have worked the main issue seeming to be that both the databases share the same unique keys but also it just doesn't seem to move the data correctly:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO staging.tablename
SELECT * FROM live.tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Navicat (Trial vesion available), using Tools -> Data Syncronization

https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql